# What is this part of a double hung window sash called?

Tags: windows

A few of the covers for these are missing in my house and I can't figure out what to search for for replacements. I'm referring to the dirty, vertical rectangular thing in this picture:

[image]

[Full size picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3947T.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are safety catches that prevent the window from being opened all the way.

They pop out, and with the window unlocked, they let it open just a few inches. Supposedly an intruder cannot open the window enough to crawl in, and more importantly a child cannot crawl or fall out.

If these little catches are not in place then all you have are cosmetic closure caps.

Here is a photo:
[image]

Comment: More importantly,  they make it (more) difficult for a child to open the window far enough to fall out. Liability management...

Comment: @keshlam, you are right. I forgot to mention that.